# How to extract file name from file list?

Tags: linux, sed, awk, vi, kingsoft

Now I have several files, their names include version number, I want to extract their file name only and strip the version number,

```
ES File Explorer_3.0.5.5.apk
ES Task Manager_1.4.1.apk
Facebook_3.7.apk
Gmail_4.6 (836823).apk
Google+_4.1.2.51968121.apk
Google Play Books_2.9.21.apk
Google Search_2.8.8.849369.arm.apk
Hangouts_1.2.018 (849105-30).apk
Instagram_4.1.2.apk
Kingsoft Office_5.7.3.apk
Maps_7.2.0.apk
Skype_4.4.0.31369.apk
Translate_2.8.apk
Twitter_4.1.8L.apk
WhatsApp_2.11.93.apk
YouTube_5.1.10.apk
```

How to do? using vi, sed or awk?
Such as extract YouTube or YouTube.apk from YouTube_5.1.10.apk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F_ '{print $1 ".apk"}' file
ES File Explorer.apk
ES Task Manager.apk
Facebook.apk
Gmail.apk
Google+.apk
Google Play Books.apk
Google Search.apk
Hangouts.apk
Instagram.apk
Kingsoft Office.apk
Maps.apk
Skype.apk
Translate.apk
Twitter.apk
WhatsApp.apk
```

A version to fix `cn.msn.messenger.1370207212755.apk`

```
awk '{gsub(/[0-9].*|_/,x);gsub(/\.$/,x)} {print $0 ".apk"}' file
```

Comment: Is there any other solution to deal with cn.msn.messenger.1370207212755.apk?

Comment: It would be difficult since there are different field separators.  We could say here that last filed separated by `.` should be removed, but will not work here: `WhatsApp_2.11.93.apk`

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file | sed 's/\([^_]*\)\(.*apk\)/\1.apk/'
```

Comment: Note you can use `sed ... file` to get rid of the `cat file | sed `.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/_[^_]*.apk$/.apk/" YourFile
```

assuming the last "_" is the delimiter and is not included